# PowerShell script to simulate "Enter" press

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs a program which requires a user to press "Enter" before the script can advance.  Being that I'm trying to automate this process, I want to eliminate user involvement.  Is there a way to simulate this "Enter" press within the PowerShell script?  I have tried:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

and

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
```

but it still requires the user to press "Enter" and then it prints "False".  It then adds a return at the very end of the program regardless of this code placement in the program.

Comment: Is the program that your script runs a Windows based program or a command line program?

Answer (score 4):

I used this code at the beginning of my function:

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```