# Building CUDA in platformio-ide-terminal

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, cuda, nvcc, cl

I would like to be able to compile and build CUDA C source code provided [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example) using Windows 10 Powershell. I have no issue doing this using **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017**.

However, I have tried several ways suggested online to get Powershell to work, but no success. The reason is I want to be able to build my cuda codes in Atom, the editor, using its package [`platformio-ide-terminal`](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) that loads a Powershell inside Atom. So, if I figure out how to setup Visual Studio 2017 Community in a Powershell, I edit my code in Atom and conveniently build them using its Powershell integration.

I tried to set the environment as follows but still `nvcc` cannot find the path to `cl.exe`.

Could someone kindly help me?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\"

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build> .\vcvarsall.bat amd64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.7.3
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build> cd C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example\

PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example> nvcc .\chapter03\hello_world.cu
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a **Windows Powershell** and run the following commands at the prompt:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat' amd64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.7.3
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example> $ENV:PATH="$ENV:PATH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64"
PS C:\Users\AFP\Downloads\cuda_by_example> nvcc .\chapter03\hello_world.cu
hello_world.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp
PS C:\Users\falah\Downloads\cuda_by_example> .\a.exe
Hello, World!
PS C:\Users\falah\Downloads\cuda_by_example>
```

**Automation**

To automate this, create a file named `nvcc_setup_for_powershell.ps1` and place the following two commands in it.

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat' amd64
$ENV:PATH="$ENV:PATH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64"
Write-Output "Configured PowerShell for NVCC Using Visual Studio 2019 Community x64"
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

the last two commands is to simulate hitting enter button, adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35566520/1227860).

Open settings for `platformio-ide-terminal` under `Core > Run Command` place the path to the PowerShell script: `& "C:\Path\To\Script\nvcc_setup_for_powershell.ps1"`.

[image]
You may need to open a PowerShell as administrator and run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

to allow you to execute `nvcc_setup_for_powershell.ps1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the path to cl.exe to the environment variables:

`control panel > view advanced system settings > Environment variables > Path > New`.

Then add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\<year >\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\<toolset>\bin\Hostx64\x64`.

Or use this command for compile: `nvcc x.cu .\chapter03\hello_world.cu  -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\<year >\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\<toolset>\bin\Hostx64\x64"`

Comment: To get it working, I changed it path to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64`.